# Power Pivot / Data model blocking - duplication in data + tabular form not working

Tags: relational-database, powerquery, data-modeling, powerpivot

I have downloaded all my sheets in power query and made the necessary transformations, including creating a common Column ID on each sheet based on a project number and company ID (=Project number (IFS)). The goal is to create a report (in the form of a PivotTable with tabular form to display/align the data) that will relate the different sheets based on this Project ID. To create the report, I would like to create a data model and use PowerPivot object. Below is the idea of the desired report design: enter image description here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVoTf.png)

My first blocking point, once the data model is created and start using the power pivot, all the data that should be displayed in the different project number is put in line per project and duplicated in all the other project lines also. For example, 'Inspection Activities.' All the data in the PivotTable ends up in a single row in sequence and duplicates for each Project ID. Below is a screenshot of the issue. Did I miss a step? Or is this a limitation of the system?"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBXF7.png)

My second blocking point is the below error. The sheet 'Nadia POs 2020-2023' lists a set of purchase orders by projects and companies. However, it contains replicated data in the 'Project ID (IFS)' column because for each project/company, we have multiple purchase orders.

When I try to establish the relationship, I realize that it is blocking. Do you see a way to bypass this error to be able to relate it to the rest of the sheets?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN6NX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOUW2.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

I think both issues are related to your relationships being the wrong way round.

First, you need to ensure `eProject` table has unique/distinct `Project Number (IFS)` or `Project Number`, whichever is the primary key. In PowerQuery, select this column, right-click in its header and `Remove Duplicates`.

Second, you need to change the relationships between `eProject` table and the ones on the right of your data model diagram to be `1.*` (one-to-many).